# Blackberry SDK 7 on a Blackberry 6 phone

Tags: blackberry, java-me

I am having a lot of issues installing my BlackBerry app to my phone. The app has been signed but still says that there is an error of attempting to access a secure API. However, I realise my eclipse is using the 7 sdk whereas my phone is running blackberry 6. Could this be the issue?

How would I go about changing this in eclipse?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you will need to install the BlackBerry JRE 6.0.0 Plugin into your instance of Eclipse by adding BlackBerry Java Plugin - http://www.blackberry.com/go/eclipseUpdate/3.6/java to your list of 'Available Software Sites' in Eclipse->Help->Install new software.

Then when you have that installed, you will be able to right click on JRE System Library [BlackBerry JRE 7.0.0] in your project, select Properties and change to JRE 6.0.0.

Then re-package, sign and install on your OS6 device